# Can work be done on a body when temperature and pressure are changed without changing its volume?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, pressure

Can work be done on a gaseous system when temperature and pressure are changed without changing it's volume?

In chemistry the formula of work is always $p\,\mathrm dV,$ whereas we can also do work on on a gas by changing its pressure without changing the volume. Work can also be done by changing the number of moles and changing the pressure. Is the above hypothesis correct?

Comment: You can't do mechanical work on a gas by changing its pressure without changing its volume, unless the work is some sort of stirring.

Answer (score 3):

"Work", loosely speaking, is an useful quantity because of it's conservative nature, and that's what first law of thermodynamics says. Work is actually defined as

$$W_\mathrm{ext} = \int\vec{F}\,\mathrm d\vec{x}.$$

Hence you see that it's not only force that matters the force should cause a displacement of the particle which it acts on.

> we can also do work on on a gas by changing its pressure without changing the volume

You see that its not possible because there is some external force acting on the particles, but that doesn't cause any net displacement. That is the volume doesn't change. And you should self realize that changing the amount of substance won't do work on a system.

In your case, can you now prove that only $p\,\mathrm dV$ causes a net displacement on the system? Remember, even though pressure is a scalar quantity, it is not force acting per unit area but thrust acting per unit area, hence the dot product in original expression is not violated. For more queries you can visit [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Edit: Wherever I say "work" it should be understood as "mechanical work". Other forms of work are also possible as suggested by the other answer and they also obey the first law of thermodynamics. This mechanical work by stirring is a nice special case where it's hard to define pressure, but we have other easier methods in physics, have you ever heard of "[Joule's paddle wheel](http://www.eoht.info/page/paddle+wheel+experiment)"?

Answer (score 2):

The root of your confusion, as I understand, is that you are not much familiar with other kinds of work done. Although, $p\,\mathrm{d}V$ is everyone's favourite but it's not the only one in the league.

Always remember, the $p\,\mathrm{d}V$ is work done during an expansion/compression. You can change the pressure or concentration to get electric work.

Answer (score 0):

You could mechanically rotate a generator (i.e., do work) to make an electrical current which flows into a resistor within the gaseous volume and heats it. So you could say you did work on the gaseous system (indirectly), and some of it is recoverable as work by releasing the pressure.

Comment: This is not work done on the system,  it is heat transfer Q to the system( unless you consider the resistor as part of the system).